# How to work with first item of array?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

> SELECT regexp_matches('abc',
>   '[0-9]*');

The query above returns `text[]` and need to check, whether it found any (i don't care which) matches or none.

So in case above i get `{""}`, how can i get "boolean" value, which tells me if it matches something or nothing?

This seems not work:

> SELECT regexp_matches('abc', '[0-9]*')
>   = '{}';

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`~` operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE):

```
SELECT 'abc' ~ '[0-9]*';
```

Alternatively, you could pull out the first item like this:

```
SELECT (regexp_matches('abc', '[0-9]*'))[1] = ''; -- True if it didn't match
```

Note the extra parentheses and that the array is indexed starting at 1.